# Rep history shows +25 points today, but total only incremented by 10

Tags: support, reputation

Today I received an upvote and best answer for an answer I posted 3 days ago.  ([link](https://superuser.com/a/399222/76571))  However, my rep was only incremented by 10 points (from 1376 to 1386).  Here's my rep history with the two inconsistent pieces of information:

[image]

I don't believe this possibly has anything to do with rep caps.  Am I missing something, or is this a bug in rep calculation?

Comment: [Recalculate](http://superuser.com/reputation#bottom) your reputation.

Comment: @iglvzx rep recalcs are not needed anymore

Comment: @Sathya Oh, really? That's good news. :)

Comment: @iglvzx [Recent Reputation History Changes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/123319/133693)

Comment: Can you show us your profile (the reputation tab)?

Comment: At the bottom of [this page](http://superuser.com/users/76571/excellll?tab=reputation&sort=time) there is a tick, enable it and look whether something of yours was deleted. Feel free to share screen shots so we can help you figure it out...

Comment: if the tick is marked, let me know.  **Ed:** scratch that, there are only 3 deleted answers & 1 migrated question, and all have zero score - so that tick won't matter

Comment: @slhck: Please note that you can view it on his profile, it however does not show deleted stuff.

Comment: @Tom I know, that's exactly the point :)

Comment: FYI My reputation dropped a few points (I don't recall the specific amount -- somewhere around 20) a few weeks ago with the reputation system update, but I don't think that should have anything to do with the present problem.

Comment: If the issue were from deleted posts, wouldn't the negative change in my rep be posted in the summary (i.e. the screenshot above)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're the lucky winner today!  We have recalculated your reputation - there is a very rare race condition that we are aware of when reputation is updated which can cause the accept and upvote to appear to be made at exactly the same moment.  We have a plan for these but will be rolling it out in a future build.

Comment: Interesting, related race condition: [2003 North America blackout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2003_North_America_blackout#Computer_failure)

Answer (score 3):

Interesting case, your [reputation history](https://superuser.com/users/76571/excellll?tab=reputation) says your rep [should be](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0AnDc6EjXlpgbdDMzS2RvTjRnWElYck04TFJqN0dvWFE&output=html) 1404, your SU rep says it's 1386, while the accounts tab of your Meta account says SU rep is 1391

[image]

Not entirely sure what's happened - caching issues, data stores not sync'd.

Comment: **Most recent reputation system change**: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125287/no-reputation-from-suggested-edits/125411#125411